# Postgres inserting value issue - column "insert" does not exists

Tags: postgresql, triggers, insert, auto-increment

I have a table in DB:

```
<createTable tableName="api_consumer">
    <column name="id"
            type="INTEGER">
        <constraints primaryKey="true"
                     primaryKeyName="PK_api_consumer_id"/>
    </column>
    <column name="business_id"
            type="VARCHAR(50)"/>
    <column name="type"
            type="VARCHAR(32)"/>
    <column name="status"
            type="VARCHAR(32)"/>
    <column name="description"
            type="VARCHAR(256)"/>
    <column name="created_by"
            type="VARCHAR(64)"/>
    <column name="created_date"
            type="DATETIME"/>
    <column name="modified_by"
            type="VARCHAR(64)"/>
    <column name="modified_date"
            type="DATETIME"/>

    <!--TTP below-->
    <column name="name"
            type="VARCHAR(64)">
    </column>
    <column name="origin_country"
            type="VARCHAR(64)"/>
    <column name="license_authority_name"
            type="VARCHAR(64)"/>
    <column name="registration_date"
            type="DATETIME"/>
    <column name="api_callback_url"
            type="VARCHAR(256)"/>
    <column name="application_base_url"
            type="VARCHAR(256)"/>
    <column name="authorization_callback_url"
            type="VARCHAR(256)"/>
    <column name="address"
            type="INTEGER">
        <constraints foreignKeyName="FK_api_consumer_address_id"
                     references="address(id)"/>
    </column>
    <column name="local_address"
            type="INTEGER">
        <constraints foreignKeyName="FK_api_consumer_local_address_id"
                     references="address(id)"/>
    </column>
    <column name="license"
            type="INTEGER">
        <constraints foreignKeyName="FK_api_consumer_license_id"
                     references="license(id)"/>
    </column>
</createTable>
```

Generated in SQL dialect:

```
CREATE TABLE api_consumer
(
  id                         INTEGER NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT "PK_api_consumer_id"
    PRIMARY KEY,
  business_id                VARCHAR(50),
  type                       VARCHAR(32),
  status                     VARCHAR(32),
  description                VARCHAR(256),
  created_by                 VARCHAR(64),
  created_date               TIMESTAMP,
  modified_by                VARCHAR(64),
  modified_date              TIMESTAMP,
  name                       VARCHAR(64),
  origin_country             VARCHAR(64),
  license_authority_name     VARCHAR(64),
  registration_date          TIMESTAMP,
  api_callback_url           VARCHAR(256),
  application_base_url       VARCHAR(256),
  authorization_callback_url VARCHAR(256),
  address                    INTEGER
    CONSTRAINT FK_api_consumer_address_id
    REFERENCES address,
  local_address              INTEGER
    CONSTRAINT FK_api_consumer_local_address_id
    REFERENCES address,
  license                    INTEGER
    CONST
```

RAINT FK_api_consumer_license_id
    REFERENCES license
);

and from the IntelliJ DB console I am trying to insert value to this table and test my triggers on it.
My insert is like:

```
INSERT INTO api_consumer VALUES ('11', '101', 'PSD2', 'NEW', 'TEST OF TRIGGER ON INSERT', 'kkwiatkowski', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, null, null, 'SPRAWDZAM_COS', 'PL', null, null, null, null, null, 1, 1, 1);
```

And I am getting an error like:

```
sql> INSERT INTO api_consumer VALUES ('11', '101', 'PSD2', 'NEW', 'TEST OF TRIGGER ON INSERT', 'kkwiatkowski', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, null, null, 'SPRAWDZAM_COS', 'PL', null, null, null, null, null, 1, 1, 1)
[2017-10-16 10:30:43] [42703] ERROR: column "insert" does not exist
[2017-10-16 10:30:43] Gdzie: PL/pgSQL function proc_subscription_audit_insert() line 3 at SQL statement
```

Word: "Gdzie" means Where in eng.

If I delete this `id value: '11'`, then the insert query is invalid, cause the argument scope is moving on the right. Understandable.

```
[2017-10-16 10:39:08] [22007] ERROR: invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "SPRAWDZAM_COS"
[2017-10-16 10:39:08] Pozycja: 133
```

Word: "Pozycja" means Position in eng.

**1) So how can I fix that?**

**2) How can I implement auto-increment value in here?**

I have tried adding an `autoIncrement="true"` in the xml structure and then invoke this insert query without `id` argument. Neither this nor adding `nextval(id)` to the insert query works.

---

**Edit:**

procedures.xml

```
<changeSet id="1.0-procedures" author="blab">

    <sql>
        DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS proc_api_consumer_audit_insert();
        DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS proc_api_consumer_audit_update();
        DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS proc_subscription_audit_insert();
        DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS proc_subscription_audit_update();
    </sql>

    <createProcedure>
        CREATE FUNCTION proc_api_consumer_audit_insert()
        RETURNS TRIGGER AS $api_consumer$
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO api_consumer_audit(api_consumer_id, change_type, changed_by, changed_date, business_id_old, business_id_new, name_old, name_new, api_callback_url_old, api_callback_url_new, application_base_url_old, application_base_url_new, authorization_callback_url_old, authorization_callback_url_new, status_old, status_new) VALUES(NEW.id, 'INSERT', CURRENT_USER, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, null, NEW.business_id, null, NEW.name, null, NEW.api_callback_url, null, NEW.application_base_url, null, NEW.authorization_callback_url, null, NEW.status);
            RETURN NEW;
        END;
        $api_consumer$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
    </createProcedure>

    <createProcedure>
        CREATE FUNCTION proc_api_consumer_audit_update()
        RETURNS TRIGGER AS $api_consumer$
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO api_consumer_audit(api_consumer_id, change_type, changed_by, changed_date, business_id_old, business_id_new, name_old, name_new, api_callback_url_old, api_callback_url_new, application_base_url_old, application_base_url_new, authorization_callback_url_old, authorization_callback_url_new, status_old, status_new) VALUES(NEW.id, 'UPDATE', CURRENT_USER, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, OLD.business_id, NEW.business_id, OLD.name, NEW.name, OLD.api_callback_url, NEW.api_callback_url, OLD.application_base_url, NEW.application_base_url, OLD.authorization_callback_url, NEW.authorization_callback_url, OLD.status, NEW.status);
            RETURN NEW;
        END;
        $api_consumer$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
    </createProcedure>

    <createProcedure>
        CREATE FUNCTION proc_subscription_audit_insert()
        RETURNS TRIGGER AS $subscription_audit$
        BEGIN
            INSERT INTO subscription_audit(subscription_id, change_type, status_old, status_new, valid_from_old, valid_from_new, valid_through_old, valid_through_new, changed_by, changed_date) VALUES (NEW.id, INSERT, null, NEW.status, null, NEW.valid_from, null, NEW.valid_through, CURRENT_USER, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
            RETURN NEW;
        END;
        $subscription_audit$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
    </createProcedure>

    <createProcedure>
        CREATE FUNCTION proc_subscription_audit_update()
        RETURNS TRIGGER AS $subscription_audit$
        BEGIN
        INSERT INTO subscription_audit(subscription_id, change_type, status_old, status_new, valid_from_old, valid_from_new, valid_through_old, valid_through_new, changed_by, changed_date) VALUES (NEW.id, 'UPDATE', OLD.status, NEW.status, OLD.valid_from, NEW.valid_from, OLD.valid_through, NEW.valid_through, CURRENT_USER, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
        RETURN NEW;
        END;
        $subscription_audit$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
    </createProcedure>

    <rollback>
        DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS proc_api_consumer_audit_insert();
        DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS proc_api_consumer_audit_update();
        DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS proc_subscription_audit_insert();
        DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS proc_subscription_audit_update();
    </rollback>
</changeSet>
```

triggers.xml

```
    <changeSet id="1.0-triggers" author="blab">

        <sql>
            DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_api_consumer_audit_insert ON api_consumer;
            DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_api_consumer_audit_update ON api_consumer;
<!--            DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_api_consumer_audit_delete ON api_consumer-->
            DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_subscription_audit_insert ON subscription;
            DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_subscription_audit_update ON subscription;
<!--            DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_subscription_audit_delete ON subscription-->
        </sql>

        <createProcedure>
            CREATE TRIGGER trg_api_consumer_audit_insert
            AFTER INSERT ON api_consumer
            FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE proc_api_consumer_audit_insert();
        </createProcedure>

        <createProcedure>
            CREATE TRIGGER trg_api_consumer_audit_update
            AFTER UPDATE ON api_consumer
            FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE proc_api_consumer_audit_update();
        </createProcedure>

        <createProcedure>
            CREATE TRIGGER trg_subscription_audit_insert
            AFTER INSERT ON api_consumer
            FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE proc_subscription_audit_insert();
        </createProcedure>

        <createProcedure>
            CREATE TRIGGER trg_subscription_audit_update
            AFTER UPDATE ON api_consumer
            FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE proc_subscription_audit_update();
        </createProcedure>

        <rollback>
            DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_api_consumer_audit_insert;
            DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_api_consumer_audit_update;
            DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_subscription_audit_insert;
            DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS trg_subscription_audit_update;
        </rollback>

    </changeSet>
```

Comment: Did you tried to do that insert with column list? Please post sql code, not that IntelliJ xml schema.

Comment: No I didn't. All the methods I had used I wrote up here. I have edited my post with generated sql code

Comment: So the SQL code is generated from the IDE? If so, it does it wrong by ommiting column list. Secondly the primary key column should be bigserial pseudo type (which solves problem for the autoincrement) or should have default with nextval for the sequence.

Comment: Show code of `proc_subscription_audit_insert()`

Comment: I didnt see that earlier, and I dont know how it is using proc_subscription_audit_insert(), when it should use: proc_api_consumer_audit_insert().... Added by edit

Comment: Unrelated, but: do not put numbers into single quotes. `'11'` is a string. `11` is a number. You wouldn't (and can't) write `int foo = "11";` in Java either

Comment: So in that function you have unquoted string INSERT: `VALUES (NEW.id, INSERT, null, NEW.status, `. You need to quote it just like in the rest of those trigger functions.

Comment: yeah right, but it didnt fix this issue :/

Comment: yes it did. please create another question (without the error) and ask a single question please

Comment: Did you put back that value you have removed previously? `'11'`. You didn't specify column list in your insert, so you need that primary key as well.

Comment: Ok, I will try that all. When I was writing a response, a several new comments appears. Sorry for a mess.